# undefined method `current_user' for #<Teacher:0x00000004fcac48>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Devise gem in my Rails project. The reason I use Devise is because I want just logged in user can rate their teachers. Now, I get this error in my ratings_controller.rb although I already added user_id into my ratings and teachers table.

```
undefined method `current_user' for Teacher:0x00000004fcac48
@rating = @teacher.current_user.ratings.build
```

Here is my **ratings_controller.rb**:

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    get_teacher
    @rating = @teacher.current_user.ratings.build
  end

  def create
    get_teacher
    @rating = @teacher.current_user.ratings.create(rating_params)
    if @rating.save
      redirect_to school_teacher_path(@teacher.school, @teacher)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    get_teacher
    @rating = @teacher.ratings.find(params[:id])
    @rating.destroy

    redirect_to school_teacher_path(@teacher.school, @teacher)
  end

  def get_teacher
    @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])
  end

  private

    def rating_params
      params.require(:rating).permit(:easiness, :helpfulness, :clarity, :comment,
      :teacher_id, :school_id)
    end
end
```

**rating.rb:**

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**teacher.rb:**

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users

  def name
    "#{firstName} #{middleName} #{lastName}"
  end

  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :teachers
end
```

Comment: `@teacher.current_user` - what were you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Do you read the [Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change several code here. Before fixing your code, I suggest you to user `before_action` to make DRY code.

```
class RatingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :get_teacher

  # your code #

  private
    def get_teacher
      @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])
    end

    def rating_params
      params.require(:rating).permit(:easiness, :helpfulness, :clarity, :comment, :teacher_id, :school_id)
    end
end
```

Then, add `before_action :authenticate_user!` above `before_action :get_teacher` so you can get `current_user` in each method.

Finally, you have to fix your `new` and `create` method into this:

```
def new
  @rating = current_user.ratings.build
end

def create
  @rating = current_user.ratings.create(rating_params)
  if @rating.save
    redirect_to school_teacher_path(@teacher.school, @teacher)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

You do not need to `@teacher.current_user.ratings.create(rating_params)` to get `teacher_id` because you have `teacher_id` in your `rating_params`. I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I will try it when I get back to it tomorrow. Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 1):

`current_user` is a controller helper, it's not a instance method of model.

you can add `before_action :authenticate_user!` in controller to make sure only logged in user can rate

Comment: Thank you for your help. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build rating object for user like this:-

```
@rating = current_user.ratings.build
```